# Yum Install libhdf5-dev on Amazon Linux

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, hdf5

I am working on deploying project that uses hdf5 as a dependency:
http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html
And I am having a devil of a time install one of the dependencies for my elastic beanstalk deployment.

HDF5 1.8.4 or newer, shared library version with development headers (libhdf5-dev or similar)

Yum cannot seem to find it no matter the options:

"No package libhdf5-serial-dev available.
No package libhdf5-dev.  No package libhdf5-devel.
No package hdf5-tools available."

Any pointers on what command I can run during deployment to get this install would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that Amazon Linux is a modification of RHEL - so the package manager is yum.
The development lib of hdf5 for CentOS is `hdf5-devel`:

For **CentOS**

```
yum -y install hdf5-devel
```

The current version is (which will get installed) `1.8.12`

---

For **Ubuntu**:

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
```

Answer (score 12):

On Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, I can't install hdf5 using any of the listed package names. You have to run `sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel` first in order to add extra packages to your configuration.

Comment: This should be included in the answer.. Or the above installation won't work.

Comment: that didn't work for me, I had to do follow instructions here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/

Comment: I also had to follow the link @amohr posted.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
sudo yum install –y epel-release
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum install hdf5-devel
```

It works for me.

Comment: Worked for me on `manylinux_2_28` image (used `dnf` to enable repo)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the PowerTools repository in order to install `hdf5-devel`

```
dnf config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
dnf update
```